# No operator matchesYou might need to add explicit type casts django postgres

Tags: django, postgresql

i was trying to access artist_type based on id when i try domain.com/artist/3 i get this error:

```
operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...main_site_artist" WHERE "main_site_artist"."artist_type" = 3
                                                                ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

as i can see in table there are 2 artist_type with id 3.
as i am filtering artist based on artist_type

this is models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class artist(models.Model):
  CHOICES = (
      (0, 'celebrities'),
      (1, 'singer'),
      (2, 'comedian'),
      (3, 'dancer'),
      (4, 'model'),
      (5, 'Photographer')
  )
  artist_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
  artist_type = models.IntegerField(choices = CHOICES)
  description = models.TextField(max_length = 500)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.artist_name
```

this is my database table:

```
celeb=# select * from main_site_artist;

id | artist_name | artist_type |  description   
----+-------------+-------------+----------------
1 | test        | 1           | test
2 | aka         | 3           | aka
3 | test2       | 4           | aka
4 | sonu        | 3           | aka moth
5 | norma       | 0           | its norma here
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views



urlpatterns = [
 path('',views.index, name='mainsite-index'),
 path('about/',views.about, name='mainsite-about'),
 path('contact/', views.contact, name='mainsite-contact'),
 path('artist/<int:artist_type>/',views.talent, name='mainsite-talent'),
 path('book_artist/', views.artist_booking, name="artist_book")
```

]

views.py:

```
 def talent(request, artist_type):
        artists = artist.objects.filter(artist_type = int(artist_type))
        context = {
                 'aka': artists
        }
        return render(request, 'main_site/talent.html', context)
```

this is base.html where i will click :

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu nav-font" style="margin-top: 7px">
            <li> <a href={% url 'mainsite-talent' artist_type='0' %} style="color:grey;padding-left:5px">Celebrities</a></li>
             <li> <a href={% url 'mainsite-talent'  artist_type='1' %} style="color:grey;padding-left:5px">Singer</a></li>
             <li> <a href={% url 'mainsite-talent' artist_type='2' %} style="color:grey;padding-left:5px">Comedian</a></li>
             <li> <a href={% url 'mainsite-talent' artist_type='3' %} style="color:grey;padding-left:5px">Dancer</a></li>
             <li> <a href={% url 'mainsite-talent' artist_type='4' %} style="color:grey;padding-left:5px">Model</a></li>
             <li> <a href={% url 'mainsite-talent' artist_type='5' %} style="color:grey;padding-left:5px">Photographer</a></li>
                                 </ul>
```

now when i access localhost:8000 i get this error:

```
Reverse for 'mainsite-talent' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['artist/(?P<artist_type>[0-9]+)/$']
```

and with localhost:8000/artist/3 still same error:

```
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: try `artists = artist.objects.filter(artist_type = int(artist_type))` as its saying to explicitly typecast it

Comment: it not working but it should work because i'm storing choices in integer

Comment: can you run the same code in postgres like `select * from main_site_artist where artist_type=3` and check if it returns or gives error

Comment: it showing the same hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Comment: try the answer i have provided, change as i have said

Comment: it still shows same error when i query select * from main_site_artist where artist_type like '3'; then its showing results

Comment: The error is a postgres error, not django/python. It's saying the `artist_type` field is character varying, not integer. Presumably it should be integer, so something went wrong when creating the table. Apart from actually fixing the table, in order for the query to work you will have to either cast the `artist_type` field to integer (again, at the postgres level), or the value you're comparing it to (e.g. 3) to character varying. The query should look something like this: `... WHERE CAST("main_site_artist"."artist_type" AS INTEGER) = 3`

Comment: it worked i alter the column type to integer